# consuming duplicate messages from Kafka topic

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I am facing issue like consuming duplicate messages from Kafka topic. below are config parameters i used in my project.

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.downstreamsyncup.destination=gvmsr-snap-syncup-stage
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.downstreamsyncup.content-type=text/plain
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.downstreamsyncup.binder=kafka1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.downstreamsyncup.group=gvmsr-snap-syncup-consumer-group-stage
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.downstreamsyncup.consumer.auto-commit-offset=false
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.downstreamsyncup.consumer.ack-each-record=true
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.downstreamsyncup.consumer.max-attempts=9999
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.downstreamsyncup.consumer.back-off-initial-interval=1000
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.downstreamsyncup.consumer.back-off-max-interval=300000
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.downstreamsyncup.consumer.back-off-multiplier=2.0
```

Comment: Expand on your question.  If the Kafka topic has 100 messages that are exactly the same, they are duplicate and valid.  If the Kafka topic has 1 message and your program consumes the exactly same message more than once, then there is a problem.

Comment: You have `auto-commit-offset=false`, so if the consumer ever restarts and you have not committed those offsets manually on your own, then you'd reconsume the same offsets, assuming `auto.offset.reset=earliest`